# How to install EditorConfig NetBeans Plugin?

Tags: netbeans, installation, editorconfig

I want to install EditorConfig NetBeans Plugin by following instructions on this link: https://github.com/welovecoding/editorconfig-netbeans#readme, but it doesn't help me a lot. At instructions sections, it is written:

```
mvn clean install
```

I ran this command on cmd and git, but It didn't work. So where should I run this command? And in which directory should i keep my pluging files?

Regards.

Comment: Check the readme. This instruction is for building the tool yourself with Maven. I would suggest that you get the release build instead.

Answer (score 3):

To build plugin from source on Windows you first need to configure few things.

#### 1. Install JDK (Java SE Development Kit).

Get it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. Install with default settings.

#### 2. Download Apache Maven

Get it from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi. Extract archive content preferably to some short path.

#### 3. Set `JAVA_HOME`

Go to  **Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> System -> Advanced System Settings ->Environment Variables**

Add new user environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and set it to newly installed JDK.

#### 4. Add Maven bin folder to `PATH`

Like above edit user `PATH` variable and add new path for extracted archive like `C:\maven\bin`.

#### 5. Check if mvn works

In cmd type `mvn -v`.
Output should look similar to:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: C:\maven\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_121, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

#### 6. Get editorconfig-netbeans repository

Git clone or download zip from https://github.com/welovecoding/editorconfig-netbeans.

#### 7. Build new plugin

Inside editorconfig-netbeans folder run

```
mvn clean install
```

This will build plugin and run test. New plugin (`.nbm` file) will be inside /target folder.

#### 8. Install plugin

In Netbeans go to **Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded**. Use `Add Plugins...` button to add new `.nbm` file and install it.

### OR

You could save yourself all trouble and get build versions from https://github.com/welovecoding/editorconfig-netbeans/releases

Answer (score 0):

Download pre-built release here: https://github.com/welovecoding/editorconfig-netbeans/releases.

Then in netbeans, use the Tools Menu: Tools -> Plugins.

Go to the 'Downloaded' tab, and click on 'AddPlugins...'  Navigate to where the release was downloaded, then click the install button.